# Can't connect to MySQL from Cygwin

Tags: mysql, cygwin

When I call mysql from cygwin terminal I tried that:

```
 $ mysql -u root -p
```

Works well from cygwin.bat but doesn't work from the regular shell ..
So I copied mysql.exe from its folder to cygwin/usr/local/bin.

Then I typed which mysql:

```
 $ which mysql
 /usr/local/bin/mysql
```

but still .. mysql doesn't seem to load in cygwin 64 Terminal

I read lots of posts about this issue but couldn't find a proper solution. Anyone has a solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not using the cygwins mysql-client (database package)?

Comment: by starting the setup tool setup-x86_64.exe (or maybe a 32bit version) - available on the cygwin homepage. Click 6 on 'next', type 'mysql' into 'search', choose the 'mysql client' and a last 'next' again ;)